# Add selected row from a table to another table with Jquery and MVC3

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, html-table

I am using MVC 3, EF Model First on my project.

In my View I have 4 tables that look likes these.

```
<div class="questionsForSubjectType">  
            <table>
                <thead>
                  <tr>
                     <th>
                       Title
                     </th>
                  </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody>
                    <tr>
                      <td>
                         test
                     </td>
                   </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>           
</div>
```

users should be able to select and add to another table lets say the table is following:

```
    <table id="CustomPickedQuestions>


   /* <----- Questions that users chose from the other tables /*

    </table>
```

What I am looking for is that when a users click on a row, the row shall get removed and added to the `CustomPickedQuestions`, When the row is added to that table, the user should also be able to remove it from `CustomPickedQuestions` `Table` and then that row shall go back to the `Table` it was before.

I now wonder how I can accomplish this with help of client-side jquery scripting.

Comment: Do you want to implement something like this: http://jqueryui.com/demos/droppable/#shopping-cart ?

Comment: Hmmm I was looking for something more usable function like I explained above. And later its also suppose to be able to delete custompicked questions.

Comment: Well, then just clone dom object with jquery clone and then append with jquery append, something like `$(".questionsForSubjectType tr").click(function() { $(this).clone().appendTo("#CustomPickedQuestions tbody") }); ` - when row clicked it will be copied to target table

Comment: I tried that jquery script It didnt work is, do I need to have something inside my <tbody></tbody>?

Comment: you need to add empty tbody (otherwise selector won't work). Use tbody/thead to distinguish from header. Sample http://jsfiddle.net/xzCdU/

Comment: Its working but I dont know if I can use Clone beacuse I am suppose to have 2 different function add when i click and delete when i click on the row inside the CustomPickedTable, also when the row is clicked it should be removed from the table and when I remove it from my CustomPickedTable it should get back to the table their i clicked it in first place. Is there any other solutions then clone?

Comment: Well, just remove clone from my code - and it will move instead of copy =)

Answer (score 0):

You've got far too much irrelevant complexity in you code (for the specific question you ask). The title is good, but not the code. Rather than posting your complex project code, create the simplest possible reproduction of the problem using the least amount of code/methods/properties (with common names, that is ProductID, ProductName, etc). part 3 of my tutorial shows how to do this. See http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/javascript/working-with-the-dropdownlist-box-and-jquery/adding-a-new-category-to-the-dropdownlist-using-jquery-ui